# Search Active Directory (AD LDS) by DateTime custom attribute

Tags: c#, active-directory, custom-attributes, adam, adlds

I have added custom attribute `lastLogonTime` syntax: `UTC Coded Time`. I extended `UserPrincipal` class to GET/SET that custom attribute.

[image]

```
...
[DirectoryProperty("lastLogonTime")]
public DateTime? LastLogonTime
{
   get
   {
      object[] result = this.ExtensionGet("lastLogonTime");
      if (result != null && result.Count() > 0) return (DateTime?)result[0];
           return null;
   }
   set
   {
      this.ExtensionSet("lastLogonTime", value);
   }
}
...
```

I have also extended `AdvancedFilters` to be able to search by this custom attribute.

```
MyUserPrincipalSearch searchFilter;

new public MyUserPrincipalSearch AdvancedSearchFilter
{
   get
   {
      if (null == searchFilter)
          searchFilter = new MyUserPrincipalSearch(this);
      return searchFilter;
   }
}

public class MyUserPrincipalSearch: AdvancedFilters
{
   public MyUserPrincipalSearch(Principal p) : base(p) { }
   public void LastLogonTime (DateTime? lastLogonTime, MatchType mt)
   {
     this.AdvancedFilterSet("lastLogonTime", lastLogonTime.Value, typeof(DateTime?), mt);
   }
}
```

Now, I would like to search through all users who has `lastLogonTime` less than a  `day`.

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = ADLDSUtility.Users)
{
   MyUserPrincipal filter = new MyUserPrincipal(ctx);
   filter.AdvancedSearchFilter.LastLogonTime((DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(1,0,0,0,0)), MatchType.LessThan);
   PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(filter);
   foreach (MyUserPrincipal p in ps.FindAll())
   {
      //my custom code
   }
}
```

The above search is not returning me any results. I have test users who have not logged in in the last couple days.

I have tried `MatchType.GreaterThan`, `MatchType.Equals`. None of them are returning any results, yet there're users who match those criteria.

The only filter that does work is

```
filter.AdvancedSearchFilter.LastLogonTime(DateTime.Now , MatchType.NotEquals);
```

But this is basically returning all users. Any ideas why my search result is not returning any results?

**My goal is to search for all users who's last logon time is less than `X` days.**

I'm open to other solutions as long as I get those users.

*P.S. I do know a way around this. Loop through all users, get their `lastLogonTime` and then do a comparison, but that's just an overkill for what I'm doing.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending sometimes on this issue, I found the problem.

As I mentioned on my post the custom attribute `lastLogonTime` has syntax: `UTC Coded Time`. However, the date and time is not getting stored as `DateTime`. It's actually getting stored as `string` in this format:

> yyyyMMddHHmmss.0Z

How I ended up solving this issue is by modifying my `AdvancedSearchFilter.LastLogonTime` to search using formatted string.

```
public void LastLogonTime (DateTime? lastLogonTime, MatchType mt)
{
   const string lastLogonTimeFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmmss.0Z";
   this.AdvancedFilterSet("lastLogonTime", lastLogonTime.Value.ToUniversalTime().ToString(lastLogonTimeFormat), typeof(string), mt);
}
```

Hope this helps someone.